# How to specify --form parameter and PUT argument in php curl ?

Tags: php, curl

I have to execute this curl command in php:

```
curl --digest -u YourApiKey:YourApiSecret "http://api.moodstocks.com/v2/ref/YourID" --form image_file=@"image.jpg" -X PUT
```

So far I have this:

```
function ms_addimage($file, $hash_id){

        $postdata = array("image_file" => "@/".realpath($file));

        $opts[CURLOPT_URL] = $this->API_BASE_URL . "ref/".$hash_id;
        $opts[CURLOPT_VERBOSE] =1;
        $opts[CURLOPT_POST] =true;
        $opts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] =$postdata;


        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);

        $raw_resp = curl_exec($ch);

        echo "Response " . $raw_resp . "\n";


        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

The file path is correct but I am missing something. 
How do I pass the --form parameter and the PUT argument?

Comment: Use `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` for custom HTTP request method `PUT`. Use `CURLOPT_USERPWD` for username:password authorization. Use `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH` = `CURLAUTH_DIGEST` for digest auth.

Comment: how should I use the CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST for putting the PUT? I am adding the image_file in the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS...does that make sense?

Comment: See here: http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php. Your postfields are correct just remove the slash `@/` should be `@`.

Comment: thank you so much... it was the CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST opt ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was missing the following:

```
$opts[CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST] = "PUT";
```

Now it is working.